# How can I search bounties in my tags

Tags: feature-request, questions, bounty, search

How can I search bounties in my tags?
I can search questions with bounties (Featured) but can't filter it with my tags
(intags:mine)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a workaround, but you can type the tags you're interested in in the search bar seperated by an `or` and then go the the Featured tab. For example, if you want to search for bounties in [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), type `[html] or [javascript] or [c++]` in the search bar and go into the Featured tab:

[image]

Note that this won't work if you type anything else than `or` or a tag name in the search bar.

---

Alternatively, if you go into the Featured tab without searching for anything, questions in any of your favorite tags will be highlighted in yellow:

[image]

However, questions in other tags will also show up, they will just not be highlighted.